# can `ros2 topic list` poll periodically?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe I imagined this - but was there once a way to run `ros2 topic list` and not have it exit immediately, but rather poll periodically and list all topics that it eventually sees?

I can't find any reference to this in the git history - but I also can't believe I completely imagined this feature.

I'm interested in having `ros2 topic list` monitor some other processes that get launched, and then check the list of all topics that were seen - even ones that appeared later, or went away at some point.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330916/can-%60ros2-topic-list%60-poll-periodically?/) by [Pete B](https://answers.ros.org/users/39471/pete-b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2019-08-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try using the option `--spin-time`, which will cause `ros2 topic list` to wait for the specified number of seconds before returning. Note, it will only wait if a daemon is not already running. E.g. when running `ros2 topic list --spin-time 3` consecutively, only the first call will wait 3 seconds and the others will return immediately since the daemon was started by the first call.

You can force the discovery time to happen by first stopping the daemon:

```
ros2 daemon stop
ros2 topic list --spin-time 3
```

I'm not sure this is quite the feature you are looking for though. `ros2 topic list` does not provide a way to periodically poll for topics.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2019-08-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pete B](https://answers.ros.org/users/39471/pete-b/) on 2019-08-22**:
It seems I was mis-remembering how the --spinp-time option worked.  When I looked at this a few months ago, I must have overlooked the part about the daemon

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't exist in ROS2. If you're on Linux, you should be able to use some utilities to do what you want:

`watch ros2 topic list` will show the current topics (by default every 2 seconds) but won't accumulate like you want.

Try this two-liner shell (bash or bash-like) script to gather all the topics into a file called topics.txt:

`> topics.txt`

`while true; do ros2 topic list | sort -u -o topics.txt topics.txt -; sleep 1; done`

---

Originally posted by [DanRose](https://answers.ros.org/users/43942/danrose/) with karma: 274 on 2019-08-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1